# How to show pop up dialog only for first visit?

Tags: jquery, popup, local-storage

I have created one pop-up `div` on my web page. I wanted to show it only on the first load, but not for any other page load.

Below is the JS code and the HTML.  I tried many ways like localstorage and cookies, but failed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = '#dialog';
  var maskHeight = $(document).height();
  var maskWidth = $(window).width();
  $('#mask').css({
    'width': maskWidth,
    'height': maskHeight
  });
  $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
  $('#mask').fadeTo("fast", 0.9);
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var winW = $(window).width();
  $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
  $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);
  $(id).fadeIn(1000);
  $('.window #close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });
  $('#mask').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div style= "display:none;" id="dialog" class="window">
   <div id="close"><a href="#" class="close agree"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></a></div>
   <div id="lorem"><div><img src="<?=base_url()?>front/images/mobile_pop_bg.png"   alt="get ealaniah mobile app" title="get mobile app" ></div></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 1478px; font-size: 32pt; color:white; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with doing saving anything on client side, is that the user can  reset that information. So your pop-up will show up more than once. If you truly want to only show the popup once you will need server side persistence storage to say if it has showed for the user or not.

Comment: Thank you GH9 & Rino Raj the answers from you both are working for me.I opted one method form it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null))
    // code to show popup
    sessionStorage.setItem('dontLoad', 'true');
  }
});
```

The [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) property allows you to access a session Storage object. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/yj4thbcv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var Foo = function(){

     var hasShownLocalStorageName = 'bob';
     this.HasShown = function() {
          localStorage.getItem(hasShownLocalStorageName) || false
     };
     this.SetShown = functioN(){
          localStorage.setItem(hasShownLocalStorageName ,true);
     };

}
```

**usage**

```
if (Foo.HasShown())
{
//do popuplogic
Foo.SetShown()
}
```

With the caveat that the user can reset your localstorage anytime. But the same basic principle applies if you use a cookie.

Comment: Thank you for the helping answer.Your method is working for me.